Only count cells with text, not formulas in Excel
I have a range (suppose A20:A40) and in each cell there is a formula that updates its contents based on another, completely separate cell. In the rage, the cells either contain text or are empty. When I try to count the number of items in the range, Excel also automatically counts the empty cells that only contain formulas.
I have already attempted
=COUNTA,
=COUNTIFS(A20:A40,""), and
=COUNTIFS(A20:A40,"?*")
and none of them have worked.
How do I get it to only count the cells with text?

=SUMPRODUCT((A20:A40<>"")*(NOT(ISFORMULA(A20:A40)))

You could count if a cell contains a formula - to check if a cell has a formula, check this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1314724

If each cell contains a formula, then none of them are empty. A formula returning "" is not empty.

Count Cells Not Returning Nothing in a Range of Formulas

Once you say "in each cell there is a formula" none of the cells can ever be blank. Therefore COUNTA(A20:A40), which returns the number of non-blank cells, is useless since it will return the same as ROWS(A20:A40).
Once you say "the cells either contain text or are empty", by empty you mean contain Nothing, you have previously ensured this is the case.

COUNTBLANK

COUNTBLANK counts the number of cells that are blank or contain Nothing which could be useful:
=ROWS(A20:A40)-COUNTBLANK(A20:A40)



But there are ways that don't require you to write A20:A40 twice.
COUNTIF(S)

It is irrelevant whether you use COUNTIF or COUNTIFS in this particular case.
=COUNTIF(A20:A40,"*")
=COUNTIF(A20:A40,"<>"&"")
=COUNTIF(A20:A40,"<>")


If you use COUNTIFS, you can easily add another pair of arguments (conditions).


SUM(PRODUCT)

Each of the following will produce the same result.
=SUMPRODUCT(N(A20:A40<>""))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A20:A40<>""))
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A20:A40<>""))
=SUMPRODUCT(0+(A20:A40<>""))

If your version of Excel supports dynamic arrays (Excel 2021, MS365) you can 'scratch' PRODUCT i.e. use =SUM(...).

Why would anybody use SUM(PRODUCT) instead of COUNTIF(S)?
If the range A20:A40 would be an array e.g. =TRANSPOSE(A20:A40), COUNTIF(S) wouldn't work.



I often use
=SUM(--(LEN(TRIM(range)) > 0))


